# pigeonhole principle - 15 subjects, 18 students, each student takes 4 subjects. Prove there are 2 students with same 2 subjects.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

There are 15 subjects in a school. Every student takes 4 subjects out of them. Given that the
school has 18 students, prove that 2 of the students have 2 common subjects.

---

I got the number of subject combinations being 15C4 = 1365. But I don't see how this is helpful as we are only interested in two students having two common subjects. I know the 'pigeons' in this case would be the number of students, but I don't know what the 'pigeonholes' would be (which I supposed would be less than 18 then we can prove it is true using the principle).

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have no clue how to complete this question. I got there are 15C4 = 1365 subject combinations but we are only interested in having 2 same subjects so this doesn't help.

Answer (score 5):

There are 105 pairs of subjects. Each of the 18 students chooses 6 pairs, which makes 108 pairs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't start writing combinations without knowing what are the elements you're combining. A better way to start the proving is assuming the initial statement is false.
**Hint: Use the pigeonhole principle** and you will get a contradiction assigning each student different subjects avoiding the case 2 of them have the same 2 subjects.
**For example:**
Student A have subjects (1,2,3,4)
Student B have subjects (5,6,7,8)
SC have (9,10,11,12)
SD have (13,14,15,1)
SE have (2,6,9,13)
SF have (3,7,10,14)
...
And eventually you'll run out of subjects without more than 2 students.

Comment: Would there be a more elegant way to solving this, rather than assigning subjects to each student and prove that there is a contradiction? I don't see how the pigeonhole principle is used in this method.

Comment: I gave you this hint because I'm assuming you know what the Pigeonhole Principle is. If you need a more explicit hint just express what part of the solution you're stuck with.

Comment: Thank you for your help